# Magento connect features are not working

Tags: php, magento

I recently installed magento on two different domains. I tried installing the addons using magento connect manager but it is displaying an error as follows on both domains:

**community/magento_classic_theme_free: Failed to connect to 208.86.253.231: Permission denied**

Then I tried to configure my moneybookers account with magento and this also fails to connect to moneybookers (displaying connection error). This leads me to believe that non of the connection feature are working in my magento installation. Can someone please help with this?

attached screenshot shows the error.

[magento connect error http://www.magentocommerce.com/?ACT=25&fid=83&aid=31740_DgkkHDoDRpSfuMgt5t5q&board_id=1](http://www.magentocommerce.com/?ACT=25&fid=83&aid=31740_DgkkHDoDRpSfuMgt5t5q&board_id=1)

Comment: "Permission denied". Sounds to me like there is a permissions issue.

Comment: do you mean the folder permission issue?, if yes which folder do I need to change the permission of?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. I'm not sure how you have things setup, so I can't tell you which to change. I'd start here `/magento_classic_theme_free`

Comment: File permission doesn't solve it

Comment: It seems like an issue with mage. The ip address in the error takes to an address that displays mage2

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. My hosting account was blocking the outgoing connections and had to explicitly allow the displayed ip address in cpanel of the hosting account.